# Displaying Image Thumbnails instead of Image Path in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

Kind of a newbie questions, but how do I display a thumbnail of an image instead of the path to said image in the default Django admin? Heres what I have so far:

Models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="media")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Image(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def admin_thumbnail(self):
        return u'<img src="%s" />' % (self.image.url)
    admin_thumbnail.short_description = 'Thumbnail'
    admin_thumbnail.allow_tags = True
```

Admin.py

```
from .models import Project, Image

class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image
    extra = 0

class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['project']}),
        (None,               {'fields': ['title']}),
        (None,               {'fields': ['image']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]

class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['name']}),
        (None,               {'fields': ['thumbnail']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ImageInline]
    search_fields = ["name"]


admin.site.register(Project, ProjectAdmin)
admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin)
```

I don't know if there is an easier way of doing this or not, but whatever answer will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach, add this method in your models which have images:

```
def image_tag(self):
    if self.thumbnail:
        return u'<img src="%s" style="width: 150px;" />' % self.thumbnail.url
    else:
        return 'No Image Found'
```

then call it in `admin.py` like this:

```
list_display = ('image_tag', ...)
```

Regarding to OOP, you can create a parent model and extend other models which have image from the parent, then define this method on parent class

Answer (score 0):

Create thumbnails separately, while saving the form or uploading original image. So the model only has reference to original image.

In views.py define the below filter. currency.front_image is a models.ImageField.

```
@register.filter
def get_thumb(img):
    file = img.url[1:].split("/")
    file[-1] = "thumb_" + file[-1]
    fp = os.path.join("/", *file)
    return fp
```

In the html do as below.

```
<td><img src="{{ currency.front_image|get_thumb }}" width="80"></td>
```